# dma buf sharing between multiple processes

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, v4l2

I am trying to understand the dma buf framework in linux kernel and going through this article http://lwn.net/Articles/489703/ which says

Userspace entity requests for a file-descriptor (fd) which is a handle to the
   anonymous file associated with the buffer. It can then share the fd with other
   drivers and/or processes.

My question is, "any fd allocated is unique to a process. so, i think if we pass this to another process(passed fd is invalid in this process context) how can it get the handle to dma buffer?"

Comment: @mgalgs I would like to know if it is really possible to share the fd of dma buffer with the other user space linux processes?

Answer (score 1):

The way it works is that you have to use a special fd-sharing mechanism like [unix domain sockets](http://www.thomasstover.com/uds.html) or [binder](http://elinux.org/Android_Binder).